# Wait for asynchronous task to complete before continuing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to get location coordinates via the google maps javascript api, which happens asynchronously.

Here is my function for retrieving:

```
function getCoords(input_address)
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var addr = {
        address: input_address
    };
    var callback = function(result, status)
    {
        if (status == "OK") {
            var coords = result[0]['geometry']['location'];
            console.log(coords.toUrlValue());
        }
    };
    geocoder.geocode(addr,callback);
}
```

I want to submit the coordinates along with the rest of a form via an ajax function.

However, testing out the following:

```
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     var addr = $("input[type='text']").val();
     getCoords(addr);
     console.log('should wait');
});
```

Outputs:

```
should wait
coordinates
```

Is there a way to make sure the `getCoords` function completes before the next instruction is executed?

Comment: Use a callback or a promise.

Comment: This is a FAQ. When you typed your title Stack Overflow showed you a bunch of possible same questions. The third one has the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768293/waiting-on-multiple-asynchronous-calls-to-complete-before-continuing. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011619/how-to-know-when-multiple-asynchronous-calls-to-complete-then-call-another-comma?rq=1

Comment: @Phrogz Forgive my ignorance, bu't isnt that answer specifically for  ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the callback function for this purpose, do your other job after executed `geocoder.geocode();` something like

```
function getCoords(input_address){
    ......
    ......
    geocoder.geocode(addr, function (){
          doYourJobNow(); //as suggested by tgun926
     });

}

function doYourJobNow(){
    console.log('should wait');
}

//result would be
//coordinates
//should wait
```

Comment: `geocoder.geocode()` is the asynchronous task, so doYourJobNow() would have to be run inside `geocode()`'s callback function. If you edit that, I'll mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Please have a look udpdated answer, If I got wrong then please make me correct.